# Fix path config in docker for debug

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

Hi I have a problem to config debug in my asp.net core app inside container, the debug is configured, but I have a problem with a paths, follow my config

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get install -y procps && \
    apt install unzip && \
    curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

ENV INSTALL_PATH /DevFreela

RUN mkdir $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY /DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj ./

RUN dotnet restore DevFreela.API.csproj

RUN rm DevFreela.API.csproj

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      ConnectionStrings_DevFreelaCs: Server=DB;database=DevFreela;User Id=sa;Password=Devfr33la#;TrustServerCertificate=True
    command: bash start-dev.sh
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    networks:
      - dev-freela-net
    volumes:
      - .:/DevFreela
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU6-ubuntu-20.04
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: Devfr33la#
      MSSQL_PID: Express
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - dev-freela-net

networks:
  dev-freela-net:
    name: dev-freela-net
    external: true
```

start-dev.sh

```
dotnet ef database update -s ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj
dotnet run --project ./DevFreela.API/DevFreela.API.csproj
```

when I start my container and attach using vscode it works, but when I put breakpoint and my execution arrive in point I have a problem ( view images)

My code
[image: My code]

When execution was stoped by breakpoint
[image: When execution was stoped by breakpoint]

lock at between tabs and code window a path for each file, for first a path is: DevFreela.API\Controllers\UserController.cs and the second is DevFreela\DevFreela.API\Controllers\UserController.cs

I imagine the problem is about container config path, please help me to fix a config for execution find a file in correct path, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem, it isn't in my container config but in my lauch.json used in my VSCode, for my case I need use a follow config to attach debug in container:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Docker Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeArgs": [ "exec", "-i", "devfreela-api-1" ],
                "debuggerPath": "/root/vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "quoteArgs": false
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/DevFreela": "${workspaceRoot}" 
/*I solve my problem when I set this in config, app path in container*/
            }
        }
    ]
}
```